# CSS Animation doesn't go away instantly

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I have a component that needs to slide in from left with an animation. But I need the same component to disappear instantly. But with the following code, the component comes in with the animation I want, but takes 2 seconds to disappear. How should I change this, so the component would disappear instantly?

```
@keyframes slide-in {
    from {left: -350px;}
    to {left: 0;}
}

.how {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: slide-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

for the component to disappear, I am using an ng-if (AngularJS).

```
<div class="m-b col-md-6 how">
    <p ng-if="active==1;" class="how"> First </p>
    <p ng-if="active==2;" class="how"> Second </p>
    <p ng-if="active==3;" class="how"> Third </p>
    <p ng-if="active==4;" class="how"> Forth</p>
</div>
```

And here is the code that actually modifies the value of active:

```
<div class="m-b col-md-6">
    <div class="m-b">
        <butto ng-click="active=1;"> Step 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="m-b">
        <button ng-click="active=2;">Step 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="m-b">
        <button ng-click="active=3;">Step 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="m-b">
        <button ng-click="active=4;">Step 4</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the component does disappear with the code above, but it takes 2 seconds for it to disappear!

Comment: Your question only has the slide in animation. How are you making it disappear?

Comment: Did you mean disappear AFTER the animation?

Comment: Please add enough code to your question for us to reproduce the animation.

Comment: I modified the question. Is that better?

Comment: please add also the code that manages the ng-if's. it's still unclear what changes the "active" value

Comment: Are you using ngAnimate?

Comment: I modified the question to include the code where 'active' is set. I have included ngAnimate in the project but for this specific part, I think I am using pure CSS. Unless ngAnimate would interfere and interpret things differently when it is included.

Answer (score 0):

To make an element visually disappear, you can set the opacity to 0. The element will still occupy space on the page.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98tzrvtn/1)

```
@keyframes slide-in {
    0% {left: -350px; opacity: 1;}
    99% {left: 0; opacity: 1;}
    100% {left: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

.how {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    animation-name: slide-in;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
```